# REACT NATIVE setup failed : "react-native init" doesn't work

Tags: react-native, bin

I try desperately to install react-native on my computer for 3 days, but it still doesn't work...
I read a lot : docs, forums, but nothing worked for me.

I am a real beginner, I probably missed something obvious, but I can't figure it out by myself.
This is why I am here, begging for help :/

I use WINDOWS 10

**Here are my actions.**

I followed instructions from : https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native

I installed Node JS : `node-v18.16.1-x64.msi`
I installed VS Code : `VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.80.1.exe`
I installed Android Studio : `android-studio-2022.2.1.20-windows.exe`

With latest version :

- `Android SDK Platform 34`
- `Android SDK Build-Tools 34 (build-tools;34.0.0)`

I let the default Sdk path, even if my Windows user name is not ideal (space in it)
`C:\Users\A&T CORPET\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
(I first tried to install it on C:\Android\Sdk, but it didn't work either)

On Android Studio, I added the following Sdk/Tools:

- `Android SDK Build-Tools 33 (build-tools;33.0.0)`
- `Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image (system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64)`
- `Android SDK Platform 33 (platforms;android-33)`
- `Sources for Android 33 (sources;android-33)`
- `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) (cmdline-tools;latest)`

I added the env : `ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\A&T CORPET\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
And added `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` to `Path`
*(I verified that LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\A&T CORPET\AppData\Local)*

I created a new empty folder : `S:\Documents\PROGRAMMATION\My_FirstProject`
I dropped this folder into VSCode to create a new project

Now in VSCode Powershell, I run: `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`

```
PS S:\Documents\PROGRAMMATION\My_FirstProject> npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.1 -> 9.8.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.8.1 to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\A&T CORPET\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\A&T CORPET\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A&T CORPET\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-20T16_34_40_894Z-debug-0.log
```

So I run the command in notice : `npm install -g npm@9.8.1`

```
PS S:\Documents\PROGRAMMATION\My_FirstProject> npm install -g npm@9.8.1

added 1 package in 7s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run npm fund for details
```

Then I rerun the initial command : `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`

```
PS S:\Documents\PROGRAMMATION\My_FirstProject> npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
Need to install the following packages:
react-native@0.72.3Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by uglify-js as of v3.13.0
'T' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

I don't now what to do.
Could it be related to my "A&T Corpet" user name ?
I wish I had created it without space and this &, but it is too late now, I have to deal with...

(I already uninstall / re-einstall everything, situation seems to be worse now)

If any of you has an idea, please let me know !
Thank you for reading me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running this command -  npx react-native doctor. It will tell you if there is anything wrong with your installation.

Comment: Yes I did, I obtain the exact same error...

Answer (score -1):

It definitely comes from my poor user name : "A&T Corpet"
With simple windows cmd :

```
C:\Users>cd A&T Corpet
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.
'T' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
```

Now the hard question :
Is there a complete and safe way to change it without reinstall my whole computer from scratch ?

I am so mad about me, having written such a bad username...